# CakePHP and plugins in URLs

Tags: url, cakephp, plugins, parameters

I'm using a plugin in a CakePHP app together with some (admin) views in it. The URLs inside the plugin views use a structure like:

```
$html->url(array('plugin' => 'thePlugin', 'controller' => 'theController', ...));
```

When using other URLs on the same page (e.g. in the layouts file), CakePHP attaches this plugin parameter to every URL, except the plugin parameter is set to `null`:

```
$html->url(array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'otherController', ...));
```

That's the "magic" of CakePHP. Nice!

But is there a way to disable the plugin parameter or set the default value to `null` unless the parameter is explicit set in `$html->url()`? It would save a lot of time to not rewrite each URL and add `'plugin' => null` to disable this parameter.

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cakephp 1.3 have this problem. you can't set router for each plugin. but in cakephp 2 you can set route for every plugin urls.

Comment: Thanks for this info. An update to 2.0 is not possible at the moment. A solution was to not use the full plugin. I copied the needed files into the app and used them independently from the plugin. Not the best way, but faster than an update to 2.0.